# FFmpeg combining multiple -vf filters

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I currently have two filters that work great when used individually:

`ffmpeg -i "D:\imageSequences\A.jpg" -vf scale=out_color_matrix=bt709,eq=gamma=1:saturation=1 -color_primaries bt709 -color_trc bt709 -colorspace bt709 "D:\masterFolder\A.mp4"`

and

`ffmpeg -i "D:\imageSequences\A.jpg" -vf "crop=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2" "D:\masterFolder\A.mp4"`

Would it, please, be possible to get help combining these two operations into a single command? Following similar existing threads didn't work, as none seemed to use the color profile operators present on the first command line.
I'm working on Windows' CMD.

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
ffmpeg -i "D:\imageSequences\A.jpg" -vf "scale=out_color_matrix=bt709,eq=gamma=1:saturation=1,crop=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2" -color_primaries bt709 -color_trc bt709 -colorspace bt709 "D:\masterFolder\A.mp4"
```

Comment: Worked like a charm :) Thanks for taking the time.

May I ask where you found the right syntax for this concatenation of operators?

Comment: As I know you can use as many filters as you want inside the -vf you just have to separate the options inside each filter by ":" and each separate filter by ","...easy..